# K-means metrics

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

I have read through the scikit learn documentation and Googled to no avail. I have 2000 data sets, clustered as the picture shows. Some of the clusters, as shown, are wrong, here the red cluster. I need a metrics to method to validate all the 2000 cluster-sets. Almost every metric in scikit learn requires the ground truth class labels, which I do not think I have or CAN have for that matter. I have the hourly traffic flow for 30 days and I am clustering them using k-means. The lines are the cluster centers. What should I do? Am I even on the right track?!The horizontal axis is the hour, 0 to 23, and the vertical axis is the traffic flow, so the data points represent the traffic flow in that hour over the 30 days, and k=3.

[image]

Comment: The validation of clusterings is not a well-posed problem if you don't have ground truth.

Comment: Then what is the right way to handle this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "Wrong"? Also, I don't really understand the plots. What do the dots mean? What is a single data point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciKit learn has no methods, except from the silhouette coefficient, for internal evaluation, to my knowledge, we can implement the DB Index (Davies-Bouldin) and the Dunn Index for such problems. The article here provides good metrics for k-means:

http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2012/IMECS2012_pp471-476.pdf

Comment: Update on this. There's already Davies-Bouldin Index in scikit-learn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#davies-bouldin-index

Answer (score 0):

Both the Silhouette coefficient and the Calinski-Harabaz index are implemented in scikit-learn nowadays and will help you evaluate your clustering results when there is no ground-truth.

More details here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

And here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_samples.html#sklearn.metrics.silhouette_samples

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at the Agglomerative clustering and then the subsection (Varying the metric):
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#varying-the-metric

To me it seems very similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: That will require the changing of the clustering system...I'm sure there must be a simple way around this